# How to set specific IP to socket when there are multiple IPv6 addresses bound on same interface

Tags: sockets, ip, ipv6

I'm currently upgrading a big program from IPv4 to IPv6.

In the part where multiple `setsockopt` are performed, I don't know how to set a specific source IP to the interface.

I did this to set the interface's index :

```
setsockopt(m_oClientSocket, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_MULTICAST_IF, (char *) &uiInterfaceIndex,
            sizeof(uiInterfaceIndex)
```

How does the IP is selected ? Natively by the kernel ?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with IPv4 vs IPv6? If you want to bind to a specific IP when listening, you do that in your `bind()` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a specific source address you can use the `bind()` call, just like with IPv4.

If you want to let the kernel decide which source address to use, don't use `bind()` or bind to the unspecified address. This is also the same with IPv4, but you may not have noticed because you haven't worked with systems with multiple IPv4 addresses before. They aren't as common, but they do exist :)

The unspecified address for IPv4 is `0.0.0.0`, and for IPv6 it's `::`. In both cases it's the "all zeroes" address.

If you want the details of how the kernel chooses addresses take a look at [RFC6724](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6724). There are lots of rules that apply. It can be a bit complicated to understand at first, but the idea is that the kernel should choose an address that just works.